# How to mock kotlin ByteArray using Mockito?

Tags: kotlin, mockito

When I run this:

```
class SomeTest {
    fun howToMockByteArray() {
        val bytes = Mockito.mock(ByteArray::class.java)
    }
}
```

throwing:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot mock/spy class [B
Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
 - VM does not not support modification of given type
```

How can I mock `kotlin`'s ByteArray using `Mockito`?

Comment: `val bytes = byteArrayOf()`

Comment: Yes, I wrote like this. Thanks for your koltin mockito helpers!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a mocked array of `Byte` you can do the following:

`val bytes = Mockito.mock(Array<Byte>::class.java)`

`ByteArray` on the other hand is mapped to an array of primitives, i.e. `byte []`.

Comment: Can you help me doing the same thing using "mockk" library?

Comment: This is incorrect. Using mockito-core:3.5.10 will produce the error: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot mock/spy class [Ljava.lang.Byte;
Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
 - VM does not not support modification of given type

Answer (score 4):

Personally I would not mock `ByteArray`, because it is a value type, just like `String` or `Int`. Arbitrary `ByteArray`s are also easy enough to create with Kotlin's `byteArrayOf()`.